# Get all combinations of a variable and their corresponding values in a grouped data set

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

My data looks like this:

```
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
               subid = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,4),
               time = c(16, 18, 20, 10, 11, 7, 9, 10, 11))

  id subid time
1  1     1   16
2  1     2   18
3  1     3   20
4  2     1   10
5  2     2   11
6  3     1    7
7  3     2    9
8  3     3   10
9  3     4   11
```

My goal is to transform the data to:

```
newdata <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3), 
                  subid.1 = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3), 
                  subid.2 = c(2,3,3,2,2,3,4,3,4,4), 
                  time.1 = c(16,16,18,10,7,7,7,9,9,10),
                  time.2 = c(18,20,20,11,9,10,11,10,11,11))

   id subid.1 subid.2 time.1 time.2
1   1       1       2     16     18
2   1       1       3     16     20
3   1       2       3     18     20
4   2       1       2     10     11
5   3       1       2      7      9
6   3       1       3      7     10
7   3       1       4      7     11
8   3       2       3      9     10
9   3       2       4      9     11
10  3       3       4     10     11
```

So it's not a simple reshape from long-to-wide procedure: The idea is, within groups defined by id, to take all possible combinations of
subid's and their corresponding time values, and get those into a wide format.

I know I can get all possible combinations using, for example `gtools::combinations`. The first group consists of 3 rows, so

```
gtools::combinations(n=3, r=2)
```

gives me the matrix of the new subid.1 and subid.2 pair for group id==1:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3
```

But then I don't know how to proceed (neither to reshape the group with `id==1` to this format, nor how to do that separately for each group). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with base R:

```
subset(merge(mydata, mydata, by="id", suffix=c(".1",".2")), subid.1 < subid.2)
#    id subid.1 time.1 subid.2 time.2
# 1   1       1     16       2     18
# 2   1       1     16       3     20
# 3   1       2     18       3     20
# 4   2       1     10       2     11
# 5   3       1      7       2      9
# 6   3       1      7       3     10
# 7   3       1      7       4     11
# 8   3       2      9       3     10
# 9   3       2      9       4     11
# 10  3       3     10       4     11
```

`dplyr` version:

```
mydata %>% inner_join(.,.,by="id",suffix=c(".1",".2")) %>% filter(subid.1 < subid.2)
```

`data.table` version :

```
setDT(mydata)
mydata[mydata, on="id", allow.cartesian=TRUE][subid < i.subid]
#     id subid time i.subid i.time
#  1:  1     1   16       2     18
#  2:  1     1   16       3     20
#  3:  1     2   18       3     20
#  4:  2     1   10       2     11
#  5:  3     1    7       2      9
#  6:  3     1    7       3     10
#  7:  3     2    9       3     10
#  8:  3     1    7       4     11
#  9:  3     2    9       4     11
# 10:  3     3   10       4     11
```

or to get your column names right, but it kills the fun of a short solution :).

```
merge(mydata, mydata, by="id", suffix=c(".1",".2"), allow.cartesian=TRUE)[subid.1 < subid.2]
```

Comment: I find your solution the easiest to understand and compliments for realizing that the simple selection of "subid.1 < subid.2" will get me exactly what I want. However, if my data consist of hundreds and thousands (or more) of cases, the merge will first create a huge dataset with many unnecessary rows that are pruned afterward, and I am afraid I don't have enough RAM to keep it all in memory. Therefore in this case a for/apply looping solution--only creating the rows that are really necessary in the new dataset--is preferred.

Comment: Not necessarily, you "only" create twice too much data, and you possibly cut other overheads by using simple and efficient vectorized operations, you'd have to test :). If you do, test my `data.table` solutions, I believe `data.table` has a much more efficient merge at least it saved me a few years ago in one case.

Comment: I've tested it on a larger dataset (about 500k rows) using microbenchmark and 50 runs. My own solution (which I improved a bit in the meantime) takes about 2 minutes. I don't remember your base R solution, but it was about 15 seconds I think. Your dplyr solution took 790 milliseconds on average. Both data.table solutions took about the same amount of time (understandably), about 900 milliseconds. So for my data the dplyr solution was actually faster! I guess you need much larger datasets to see the power of data.table. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2):

Forgot to state that I came up with this rather lame 4-step solution:

```
step1 <- lapply(unique(mydata$id), function(x) {
  nrows <- nrow(mydata[which(mydata$id == x), ])
  combos <- gtools::combinations(n=nrows, r=2)
  return(as.data.frame(cbind(x, combos)))
})

step2 <- dplyr::bind_rows(step1)

step3a <- merge(step2, mydata, by.x = c("x", "V2"), by.y = c("id", "subid"))
step3b <- merge(step3a, mydata, by.x = c("x", "V3"), by.y = c("id", "subid"))

step4 <- step3b[, c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5)]
names(step4) <- c("id", "subid.1", "subid.2", "time.1", "time.2")
```

It's ugly but works.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, .(subid = c(t(combn(subid, 2)))), by = id
              ][, grp := rep(1:2, each = .N/2), by = id
                ][mydata, on = .(id, subid), time := time
                  ][, dcast(.SD, id + rowid(grp) ~ grp, value.var = list('subid','time'), sep = '.')]
```

which gives you:

> ```
>     id grp subid.1 subid.2 time.1 time.2
>  1:  1   1       1       2     16     18
>  2:  1   2       1       3     16     20
>  3:  1   3       2       3     18     20
>  4:  2   4       1       2     10     11
>  5:  3   5       1       2      7      9
>  6:  3   6       1       3      7     10
>  7:  3   7       1       4      7     11
>  8:  3   8       2       3      9     10
>  9:  3   9       2       4      9     11
> 10:  3  10       3       4     10     11
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Jaap! I always have a really hard time understanding data.table functions (dplyr and reshape have my preference, or just plain chaining of apply functions). What I wonder: will this work with thousands and thousands of rows of data, or could it then potentially hog all RAM? If so, I'd prefer a for-loop or apply function that really iterates over every row of data (and/or I can parallelize to use all cores) and build up the resulting data.frame row by row. But I've heard data.table is very efficient, so perhaps that's exactly what it does underneath?

Comment: @graham I think this is a pretty efficient approach. `data.table` one of the most efficient data-wrangling packages. A for-loop or chaining *apply function will certainly be less efficient.

Comment: I'll try it on my huge dataset and see if it works. Thanks for this nice answer

Comment: @Henrik Thx for spotting the error, updated the answer now. Btw: Why did you delete your answer? It seems ok to me.